# raisepostbackevent not firing

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I am building an ASP.NET custom server control. 
I have implemented both the IPostBackDataHandler and IPostBackEventHandler.
OnPreRender I have registered the postback logic:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        if (Page != null)
        {
            Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
            Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
        }
    }
```

The control uses a ImageButton (but I have also tried with a simple Button); when it is clicked I can see the page "refreshes", and some data are posted (I checked that). 
However, I don't know why the RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArguments) is not firing.

Does anyone know what's going on? Could someone point me to the right direction to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 0):

Registering your control during `PreRender` phase is too late. You can do it during the `Load` phase instead:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (Page != null && Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
        Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
    }
}
```